# Autocomplete SAPUI5 Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mobile, autocomplete, sapui5

I've installed the Tools for developing SAPUI5 applications in my eclipse and I've created the SAPUI5 Mobile Project. However, I can't use the autocomplete yet.

In the SAPUI5 Core Libriries I can see the com.sap.ui5.mobile_1.26.3.jar but in the JS file, the autocomplete doesn't work.

How can I use de sap.m in the autocomplete?

Thanks.

Comment: There are some issues with autocomplete in Eclipse.
I'm using Webstorm, and it autocomplete works there quite well.

Comment: Netbeans also works if you use local ui5 libs

Comment: For other readers: please note that **SAP won't support SAPUI5 Tools for Eclipse any longer** after UI5 1.71. (See _[What's New in SAPUI5 1.71](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/609fd015eaf64bd2a4a5c0331590eb4c)_)

Answer (score 1):

Either use SAP WebIDE or Jetbrains Webstorm. Using eclipe is not very productive because of the lack assistance Eclipse give to you. I am using WebStorm and very satisfied with it.
Here you can find how to configure Webstorm for use with OpenUi5/SAPUI5 
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/09/22/configuring-jetbrains-webstorm-for-ui5-development

Comment: Also SAP will discontinue supporting Eclipse. _> After the release of SAPUI5 1.71, the SAPUI5 Tools for Eclipse will no longer be maintained._ [(src)](https://ui5.sap.com/1.71.4/#/topic/609fd015eaf64bd2a4a5c0331590eb4c)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able. SAP has delivered a local trial version of SAP Web IDE that contains autocomplete and more neat features. The full version is hosted by SAP in the cloud and is subscription based but the SAP Web IDE is far superior to the eclipse plugins in my opinion.

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-58926